# Continuous scroll when switching divs by `z-index`

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I making an app where I have two divs with scroll event handlers and I want to be able to have a continuous scroll between the two handler when the divs are "switched" using their `z-index`.

```
|---------- div 1 -----------| switch z-index |---------- div 2 -----------|

 <------------------------- continuous scroll ---------------------------->
```

The thing is, when the `z-index` switch happen, the scroll event is still handled by the first div until I stop scrolling and start again.

Is it possible to switch the divs event handlers as soon as they become visible using `z-index` ?

Here is a working example of the problem https://codesandbox.io/s/rrrxyyjwwp, when we zoom in on the 3d globe the view switch to the 2D map and we expect that 2D map to start zooming in in that single motion. Intead, the scroll event is still handled by the 3D globe underneath and we have to stop and restart the scroll to zoom on the map.

Edit: I also tried to switch divs by using the css `display` property and the result is the same

Thanks !

Comment: Could you please provide some demo in preview?

Comment: Probably best and easiest to solve, if you put your scroll handler on a common parent element, instead of the individual divs …? (Whether that could be a solution, depends on your specific implementation of course - without any code, hard to tell.)

Comment: @MaciejKwas Working on that right now

Comment: @MaciejKwas  I've edited the post to add a working example

Comment: Someone told me to trigger event manually to switch handler context, what do you think about this ?

Comment: @FabianN. A bit hacky but this might work, will try ;)

Comment: What I would do is just handling scroll event on outer html element and passing it down to proper component. What you need is not a native scrollbar functionality, but just a delta in scroll event, so in my opinion this would be the fastest and easiest solution.

Comment: @MaciejKwas This would be great but that would mean having to reproduce the all gesture handlers in both three js and mapbox

Comment: I tried to put a ref on each div and call `focus()` on the new when switching but this doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to catch and delegate the scroll events yourself, and then change the event handlers on the divs accordingly.

If you create a parent container which has a script attached, you can use it to determine the current position, distance and visible elements. Based on this, you can change properties on the 2 alternating elements. Roughly, something like this setup should do the trick:

```
$("#parent").scroll(function() {

//determine desired element to be active/inactive
var activeElementId = "element1";
var inactiveElementId = "element2";

setActive(activeElementId);
setInactive(inactiveElementId);

});

function setActive(elementId){
//add handler
}

function setInactive(elementId){
//remove handler
}
```

Comment: If I create a parent element that catch the scroll event, how would I forward this raw event to the currently visible child div ?